# gCalFlow (jquery plugin) date formatting - ISO to english

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have gCalFlow running for a list of daily specials (cactustaqueria.com)
it has a date formatting option that returns ISO style formatting. i would like to return more human readable dates including the day of the week. so what i have now returns the following:
8/17/13 - 8/19/13
i would like it to read

tues-wed (aug 17-19, 2013) (or something like that. the key thing is the day of the week and day of the month in language not numbers).

the code to call the function looks like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#cactuscal').gCalFlow({
        calid: 'myid@gmail.com',
        link_item_title: false,
         maxitem: 6,
         daterange_formatter: function(sd, ed, allday_p) { return (sd.getMonth()+1) + "/" + sd.getDate() + "/" + sd.getYear().toString().substr(-2)+ " – " +(ed.getMonth()+1) + "/" + ed.getDate() + "/" + ed.getYear().toString().substr(-2) }
      });
    </script>
```

instead i think if its grabbing ISO i can grab it and use the Date() method? just not sure how to go about it. would i rewrite the js files option? or do something directly within this script on the page?

this is a link to the project's github docs http://sugi.github.io/jquery-gcal-flow/

Comment: looks like i can do this with moment.js pretty easily. does anyone have an opinion of whether that makes sense or its all doable with no plugin more simply?

Comment: Really late answer, but I would always uses Moment over JS date object. Lots of writing can support that JS date object isn't very cross compatible.